# l18n keep locale variable changing link rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a rails application which must be in English or in Hungarian. The user may choose the language.
So I use [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).
The problem is that **I do not understand how to keep the variable 'locale' when the user changes page**.

```
#application_controller.rb
before_action :set_locale
def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

Thanks a lot for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way i found is to use cookie to store the choice of the user.
 Their is this wonderful tutorial which explain easily how to do it:
https://www.sitepoint.com/go-global-rails-i18n/

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your config.route.rb file to insert the new :locale parameter in urls, like this for example:

```
scope "/:locale" do
  # all your routes here
end
```

Previously, your urls looked like this: http://domain.com/banana
Now they are like this: http://domain.com/en/banana (with the locale value in place of en)